# 1 report with multiple control sources

Tags: ms-access

I have 3 Tables (Table1 , Table2 , Table3) and 9 forms(Form 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9).
Form's 1,2,3 control source is Table1. Form's 4,5,6 control source is Table 2, Form's  7,8,9 control source is Table 3. I would like to add all 9 forms to 1 Report as sub-forms. Is this possible as you can only set 1 control source for the Report.I have spent hours adding the subforms and only realized this when i finished. i hope i have not done all this for nothing. Does anyone know i can do this or if it is even possible to create 1 report with multiple sub forms that have different record source's  ?

Comment: Well yeah, you can only have one data source for your report, but your sub reports can have their own data sources. You could just create the reports individually. Then go to design view for your 'parent' report, and add subreports (select use existing report) and pick your reports.

Comment: Is `table1` related to `table2` related to `table3`? can you make on query be the control source? How are you configuring your master/child links on the subform?

Comment: I wanted to use 1 table but there where too many columns so i had to split data into 3 separate tables. I relate the tables by the primary id. so for example if you add a new record to all tables the next id given will be the same for all tables.(there are 10 records in all tables so the next id will be 11)

Comment: If i could set the ID of the subforms when the report opens that would solve my problem , Could i do that using Docmd.openReport command ?